# How to turn Listbox to Text for Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to automatize an e-mail, but I am having a problem when I try to send lines from listbox; I have tried a few different ways none that were even close to working. In addition, I don't know how to use the column. I am currrently tryying to get it to work via

```
Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 500
'    v this is a listbox
     With selecteditems
         listboxarr(1) = .List(i, 1)
     End With
Next i
```

This code throws me:

> Subscription out of Range

This is the code for the email:

```
Private Sub addcb_Click()
Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.allitems.ListCount - 1
    If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.selecteditems.AddItem Me.allitems.List(iCtr)
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.allitems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.allitems.RemoveItem iCtr
    End If
Next iCtr
End Sub


Private Sub removecb_Click()
Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1
    If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.allitems.AddItem Me.selecteditems.List(iCtr)
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.selecteditems.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
Next iCtr
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 500
'    v this is a listbox
     With selecteditems
         listboxarr(1) = .List(i, 1)
     End With
Next i

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
    .to = "Someone"
    .CC = "Someone else"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Something"
    .Body = listboxarr(1) 
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim itemsheet As Worksheet
Set itemsheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6)

For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("C2:C3285")
    With Me.allitems
       .AddItem itemname.Value
    End With
Next itemname

End Sub
```

Comment: can you please post the entire thing sequentially

Comment: How many columns are in your listbox?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I only have one column

Comment: @Nathan_Sav is this better?

Comment: You haven't dimensioned `listboxarr`. Either do this when you declare the variable or use Redim is the size is not known beforehand.

Comment: @SJR So like this?

    Dim listboxarr(1,1,500)
    ReDim listboxarr(1,1,500)

Comment: If you know the size beforehand you don't need Redim. I think the syntax should be `Dim listboxarr(1 to 500)`.

Comment: @SJR Do I need 
`Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 500
'    v this is a listbox
    With selecteditems
        listboxarr(1) = .List(i, 1)
    End With
Next i`
Or should I put it inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have allowed the MultiSelect property for the listbox to True, try this...

```
Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Assuming the name of your ListBox is ListBox1. If not, change it in the following code.

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)
            listboxarr(j) = .List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

**Edited Code:**

```
Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim found As Boolean

'Assuming the name of your ListBox is ListBox1. If not, change it in the following code.

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)
            listboxarr(j) = .List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

And then you can use it like below...

```
.body = IIf(found, Join(listboxarr, ", "), "No item selected")
```

Comment: Do i put `listboxarr(j)` in the body for the e-mail than or just `listboxarr()`

Comment: I got the error **Subscription out of Range** when putting `listboxarr(j)`

Comment: What do you want to appear in the body? listboxarr may contain multiple items in it. Also if no item was selected in the ListBox1, the listboxarr would be empty and you will get the error you are talking about.

Comment: I want all the items in listboaxarr to appear in the body

Comment: In addition, I thought, when I put it in from the other listbox, it's already selected

Comment: Is this Correct? `Listbox1.MultiSelect = i`

Comment: Better set the Multiselect property in the design mode in properties. To display all the comma separated items of the array listboxarr, try this:   .body = IIf(found, Join(listboxarr, ", "), "No item selected")   . Also if you want a line break between the items in the body, replace ", " in the above line with VbCr

Comment: found is a Boolean variable to make sure the items in the ListBox1 were selected. See the edited code.

Comment: Nothing is appearing, just "No Item Selected", I keep selecting them and they do not apppear

Comment: I am trying to figure, what's wrong and it seems like it's not recognizing the selected should I change to `SelectedItems(i)`?

Comment: I take that back it works, for some reason before it wasn't

Comment: I know you already helped me with this, but I was wondering, if you can help me  with one last thing and that is having it work with a multicolumn

Comment: Please open a new question with your new requirement and provide the full code you are currently having so that other members may also help you.