# Excel VBA: Creating an Array for a Multi-Column Listbox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45191118/1306012), I asked how to make an array for a column. Earlier I just needed one, but now I have a multi-column listbox. Using three code that was given to me,I tried to edit it to see if it worked, but I think I must be doing it wrong. Can you advise me on either if I did it correctly and it's just another part of my program or if I just need to fix it. In addition it gives me

> Subscript out of Range

This is the part that I believe needs checking:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim found As Boolean

With Me.selecteditems
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        For h = 1 To 2
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)
            listboxarr(j, k) = .List(i, h)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

And in case you were wondering this is where I use it. This takes items and establishes the format , which later is used to add and remove items items from the listbox  `selecteditems` . Which is then sent to the above task, which selects the selected objects and puts it in an array, so that later it would be used to print into an e-mail

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("A2:A3400")
    With Me.allitems
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
        .AddItem itemname.Value
        .List(i, 0) = itemnum
        .List(i, 1) = Description
        i = i + 1
    End With
Next itemname

For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("A2:A3400")
    With Me.selecteditems
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
        .List(i, 0) = itemnum
        .List(i, 1) = Description
        i = i + 1
    End With
Next itemname

End Sub


Private Sub addcb_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.allitems.ListCount - 1
        If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.selecteditems.AddItem Me.allitems.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.allitems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allitems.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr


End Sub


Private Sub removecb_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1
        If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allitems.AddItem Me.selecteditems.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.selecteditems.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: I tried to remove what I  added and even the `selecteditems`. No change.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)`needs to be 2 dimensionnal. Note then redim can only change last dimension of an array. And you forgot a `next h`. Use `option explicit`, and compile before running code.