# Multi-Column Listbox giving Subscription out of range when Transfered to Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45191118/1306012), I asked how to make an array for a column. Earlier I just needed one, but now I have a multi-column listbox. Using three code that was given to me,I tried to edit it to see if it worked, but I think I must be doing it wrong. Can you advise me on either if I did it correctly and it's just another part of my program or if I just need to fix it. In addition it gives me

> Subscript out of Range

This is the part that I believe needs checking:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim listboxarr()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim found As Boolean

With Me.selecteditems
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        For h = 1 To 2
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)
            listboxarr(j, k) = .List(i, h)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

And in case you were wondering this is where I use it. This takes items and establishes the format , which later is used to add and remove items items from the listbox  `selecteditems` . Which is then sent to the above task, which selects the selected objects and puts it in an array, so that later it would be used to print into an e-mail

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("A2:A3400")
    With Me.allitems
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
        .AddItem itemname.Value
        .List(i, 0) = itemnum
        .List(i, 1) = Description
        i = i + 1
    End With
Next itemname

For Each itemname In itemsheet.Range("A2:A3400")
    With Me.selecteditems
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
        .List(i, 0) = itemnum
        .List(i, 1) = Description
        i = i + 1
    End With
Next itemname

End Sub


Private Sub addcb_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.allitems.ListCount - 1
        If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.selecteditems.AddItem Me.allitems.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.allitems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.allitems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allitems.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr


End Sub


Private Sub removecb_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1
        If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allitems.AddItem Me.selecteditems.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.selecteditems.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.selecteditems.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.selecteditems.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: I tried to remove what I  added and even the `selecteditems`. No change.

Comment: Why not just make three separate arrays, one for each column, instead of a 2D array?

Comment: I could do that , but would that mean I should change the  i = 0 to i = 1 than?

Comment: Please clarify..

Comment: Using separate 1D arrays actually gives you more flexibility during data reporting (i.e. if you only wanted to report values in two of the three columns).

Comment: sorry I meant to say that do I change from the first code I have on the text, where it says `For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1` from i = 0 to i = 1

Comment: It would involve a bit more than that.  You need to initiate the separate arrays, and then run the code to copy the rows into each of the 1D arrays.

Comment: Like this:



`With Me.selecteditems|
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1|
        If .Selected(i) Then|
            found = True|
            j = j + 1|
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)|
            listboxarr(j) = .List(i)|
        End If|
    Next i|
End With|

With Me.selecteditems|
    For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1|
        If .Selected(i) Then|
            found = True|
            j = j + 1|
            ReDim Preserve listboxarr(1 To j)|
            listboxarr2(j) = .List(i)|
        End If|
    Next i
|End With`

Comment: I turned the excel on and off and there is no more subscrption out of range problem any more but the second listbox is not showing a second column and when I try to insert the specific code  it gives me the error 381 Invalid property array index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are populating listboxarr to display the selected items in the body of email, why not declare a string variable which contain the all the selected items from the listbox.

So try something like below...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim str As String
With Me.SelectedItems
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            For ii = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                If str = "" Then
                    str = .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                Else
                    If ii < .ColumnCount - 1 Then
                        str = str & .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                    Else
                        str = str & .List(i, ii)
                    End If
                End If
            Next ii
            str = str & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

And then use the string variable to display the selected items in the email body like this...

```
.body = IIf(found, str, "No item selected!")
```

Comment: It's not changing. Also even after making it a two column listbox. It still is not showing the other column

Comment: That might be the reason why it didn't change

Comment: I've realized my problem is between defining the selecteditems and setting it to add

Comment: That's the another issue. If your listbox called SelectedItems is populated with multiple columns, the proposed code will derive a string variable called str to hold the all the selected items of the listbox.

Comment: The problem is that the selecteditems are not showing the other column that is upposed to be in it